# Firefox MAR file location changed?

Tags: firefox, browser, updates

I have been using MAR files to automatically patch Firefox following the steps at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Manually_Installing_a_MAR_file. However, the directory http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/ directory no longer exists and has been replaced with a README.txt documenting how to use the download.mozilla.org web service.

Is there a new location for update MAR files, or even better, a way to use the releases web service to obtain a MAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer by navigating through the directories. This path is for the current latest version which is Firefox 42 32bit English version
`http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/42.0/update/win32/en-US/`